# Cannot install next-auth nextjs v14

Tags: next.js, next-auth

### While installing `next-auth with latest version of NextJs i.e v14.0 I got this error:

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: next-auth@4.24.3
npm ERR! Found: next@14.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.24.3
npm ERR! node_modules/next-auth
npm ERR!   peer next-auth@"^4" from @next-auth/prisma-adapter@1.0.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter
npm ERR!     @next-auth/prisma-adapter@"^1.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: next@13.5.6
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.24.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next-auth
npm ERR!     peer next-auth@"^4" from @next-auth/prisma-adapter@1.0.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter
npm ERR!       @next-auth/prisma-adapter@"^1.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

## Report

## npm resolution error report

While resolving: next-auth@4.24.3
Found: next@14.0.0
node_modules/next
next@"^14.0.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.24.3
node_modules/next-auth
peer next-auth@"^4" from @next-auth/prisma-adapter@1.0.7
node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter
@next-auth/prisma-adapter@"^1.0.7" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: next@13.5.6
node_modules/next
peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13" from next-auth@4.24.3
node_modules/next-auth
peer next-auth@"^4" from @next-auth/prisma-adapter@1.0.7
node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter
@next-auth/prisma-adapter@"^1.0.7" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried reinstalling NodeJs also but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe `next-auth` is not compatible for `nextjs-14` . Wait some days it will fix it